# Swift - WebView pdf viewer signature issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pdf, webview

I'm trying to show a PDF (with signature fields) through a `WKWebView`. On iOS 12 and above its works perfectly but when I run it on a device with iOS lower than 12 the signature fields its not displayed.

```
let requestObj = URLRequest(url: URL.init(string: link)!)
let preferences = WKPreferences()
preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
let webconf = WKWebViewConfiguration()
webconf.preferences = preferences
PdfViewer = WKWebView(frame: ViewDocumentiWeb.bounds, configuration: webconf)
PdfViewer.uiDelegate = self
PdfViewer.navigationDelegate = self
PdfViewer.load(requestObj)
ViewDocumentiWeb.addSubview(PdfViewer)
ViewDocumentiWeb.sendSubviewToBack(PdfViewer)
```

**Expected result (iOS12 above):**

[image]

**Result on iOS12 below :**

[image]

Comment: Check the PDF with Safari browser on the same device and observe if it's showing the signature or not

Comment: @SahilManchanda with safari it works with all iOS versions , i can see all the signature fields  (but i don't want use an external app)

Comment: I understand it was just for testing purpose. Can you provide a link to PDF so that i could give it a try

Comment: @SahilManchanda its a temp (3min) link , can i give u the pdf file?

Comment: Please email me the PDF at sahil.manchanda2@gmail.com

Comment: @SahilManchanda I sent it , reply me if you receive it

Comment: i got your email. I will look into it and give it a shot

Comment: seems like WKWebView is not fully supporting digital signatures. I tried with WKWebView it doesn't work. However, I tried to load it with UIDocumentInteractionController and it worked. But there is caveat there. it works with local files only. So if you need to view pdf from a website then you need to download it first.

Comment: @SahilManchanda Thanks you very much! I'll try ur solution .

Comment: @SahilManchanda I've just tried and its working for iOS 10 and above , so thanks you. Can u approve/confirm me that its not working with iOS lower than 10 ?

Comment: Glad it's working for you. let me download the simulator and let you know about it

Comment: @SahilManchanda I found another solution that work in all cases , i use a QLPreviewController. Thanks you anyway!

Comment: That's a better option :)